# Can an epoxy resin create a terpene polymer?

Tags: polymers

I am developing plant-based antifouling coatings that will stop barnacles binding to ship hulls for example. I have started simply by mixing specific terpenes with an epoxy resin (BISPHENOL A DIGLYCIDYL ETHER), then adding the hardener and painting this onto rocks or metal before placing them in the ocean. The results are amazing so far in that I am preventing biofouling compared to an epoxy resin control.

Does the epoxy resin I am using have the ability to alter the molecular structure of terpenes, like create a terpene polymer? The reason I am thinking about this is because of this recent publication (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.biomac.2c00721), showing terpene polymerisation that increased anti-bacterial activity.

What do you think? Could BISPHENOL A DIGLYCIDYL ETHER polymerise terpenes?

Comment: Well, this paper shows functionalised terpens. You could modify them to fit the reaction of epoxy. For example epoxidise, or add glycidyl group.